# What's grammatically wrong with this sentence?

Tags: grammar

What is wrong with 'I do have two brothers.' ? I'm doing English grammar exercise and I think that's a correct sentence. But it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you could give more information about the exercise and the context of the statement. Is it a multiple-choice or a gap-fill, for example?

Anyway, in the context of giving general information to a new acquaintance about you and your family, the sentence is ungrammatical:

> I come from Thailand. I live in Bangkok. I have two brothers. I like classical music. ...

None of these simple present tense sentences are formed with the auxiliary "*do*". The auxiliary is only needed in negative statements and questions:

> I *do* not have any brothers.
>
> *Do* you have any brothers?

However, there are contexts in which the auxiliary "*do*" is indeed used in simple present statements. One such context is to contradict a statement or assumption made by your speaking partner. Assume that she does not know you very well and says:

> If you had two brothers like me, you would know ... .

To contradict her assumption, you would say:

> I **do** have two brothers,

stressing the word *do*. This and similar uses of an otherwise unnecessary auxiliary is often called "*emphatic*". There is more information here: http://www.michellehenry.fr/emphasize.htm